# TypeError: logical_and() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: numpy

I'm trying to select the indices from 1,000 to 200,000 (including the element in the 200,000 index) and the indices from 400,000 to 600,000 (including the element in the 600,000 index) in the array and add 255 to those values. This is the code I'm using.

`Q7 = np.logical_and(Q7 > 1000, Q7 < 200000, Q7 > 400000, Q7 <= 600000)`

However, I'm getting this error: TypeError: logical_and() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given.
Any pointers where I can include four conditional statements in Numpy ?
Thank you in Advance !!

Comment: You must not edit your question to erase the actual question, and leave no context to whoever gets here

Comment: In time you will get the privilege to add comments, if you don't yet. Otherwise, do edits in a careful way so that new readers can make sense of what is going on: preferably by letting the text present untouched, and adding new finds or comments at the end of your question.

Answer (score 0):

We know from the rules of logic that:

```
A and B and C and D == (A and B) and (C and D)
```

As such:

```
A = np.logical_and(Q7 > 1000, Q7 < 200000)
B = np.logical_and(Q7 > 400000, Q7 <= 600000)
Q7 = np.logical_and(A, B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation on `logical_and`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html), this really only takes two arrays as an input argument:

> Parameters:
> `x1, x2` array_like Input arrays. If x1.shape != x2.shape,
> they must be broadcastable to a common shape (which becomes the shape
> of the output).
>
> `outndarray`, None, or tuple of ndarray and None, optional A location
> into which the result is stored. If provided, it must have a shape
> that the inputs broadcast to. If not provided or None, a
> freshly-allocated array is returned. A tuple (possible only as a
> keyword argument) must have length equal to the number of outputs.
>
> `wherearray_like`, optional This condition is broadcast over the input.
> At locations where the condition is True, the out array will be set to
> the ufunc result. Elsewhere, the out array will retain its original
> value. Note that if an uninitialized out array is created via the
> default out=None, locations within it where the condition is False
> will remain uninitialized.
>
> `**kwargs` For other keyword-only arguments, see the ufunc docs.
>
> Returns:
> `yndarray` or bool Boolean result of the logical AND operation
> applied to the elements of x1 and x2; the shape is determined by
> broadcasting. This is a scalar if both x1 and x2 are scalars.

With an important footnote:

> The `&` operator can be used as a shorthand for `np.logical_and` on boolean ndarrays.

So the correct way would be:

```py
res = (
    (Q7 > 1000) &
    (Q7 < 200000) &
    (Q7 > 400000) &
    (Q7 <= 600000)
)
```